# How to fix timed out error using python in AWS Lambda functions when i am using twilio API's

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twilio

When i am test my lambda functions. it shows errors like "Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"

Here i am make a call to user using `twilio` API using python. I tested 
the APIs in my system its working.

When i test on AWS Lambda function with same code, its shows errors like "Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import json
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
call = client.calls.create( url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml', to='+91***************', from_='+1***********')
```

> Response: {   "errorMessage": "2019-10-22T11:36:02.652Z
>   60742847-e841-449a-91d9-7c493ce0d772 Task timed out after 3.00
>   seconds" }
>
> Request ID: "60742847-e841-449a-91d9-7c493ce0d772"
>
> Function Logs: START RequestId: 60742847-e841-449a-91d9-7c493ce0d772
>   Version: $LATEST
>   [INFO]    2019-10-22T11:35:59.650Z    60742847-e841-449a-91d9-7c493ce0d772    Received
>   event: {"deviceInfo": {"deviceId": "G030PM033137TFAN", "type":
>   "button", "remainingLife": 96.8, "attributes": {"projectRegion":
>   "us-west-2", "projectName": "Make_call_mail", "placementName":
>   "make_call_mail_placement", "deviceTemplateName":
>   "make_maill_service"}}, "deviceEvent": {"buttonClicked": {"clickType":
>   "SINGLE", "reportedTime": "2019-10-22T10:57:24.729Z"}},
>   "placementInfo": {"projectName": "Make_call_mail", "placementName":
>   "make_call_mail_placement", "attributes": {"body": "Hello, \nThis is
>   from AWS IoT button", "subject": "Hello theis from AWS IoT Button",
>   "email": "nagaraju.grandhi7@gmail.com"}, "devices":
>   {"make_maill_service": "G030PM033137TFAN"}}} END RequestId:
>   60742847-e841-449a-91d9-7c493ce0d772 REPORT RequestId:
>   60742847-e841-449a-91d9-7c493ce0d772  Duration: 3003.15 ms    Billed
>   Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 85 MB  Init
>   Duration: 586.65 ms    2019-10-22T11:36:02.652Z
>   60742847-e841-449a-91d9-7c493ce0d772 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Open the Lambda function
2) Please find below **Basic Settings** window in that set Timeout info and Memory(MB) info,
By default timeout is 0 to 3 sec. you should change to **5 SEC** then we can terminate the **set Timed out error**.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y4wz.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call third party API.

AWS Lambdas run in VPC they **do not know outside Internet**

If you want to do so you should add NAT to lambda.

See [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Refer the [docs to add NAT to VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html)